# Format a DateTime using a Microsoft Word date picker content control format string

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-word, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

Microsoft Word's date picker content control (which you can add to a document through the hidden-by-default Developer ribbon) uses date/time formatting strings that are slightly incompatible with [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  For example:

[image: M/d/yyyy h:mm am/pm]

If I use the same format in DateTime.ToString:

```
DateTime.Parse("11/13/2014 12:00 PM").ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm am/pm")
```

The result is "11/13/2014 12:00 a0/p0".  The expected result is what Word displays,  "11/13/2014 12:00 PM" (yes, PM is capitalized).

Is there a safe way to use a date format extracted from a Word content control to format a date in C#?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `am` or `pm` as a [custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) specifiers.

You need to use [`"tt"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ttSpecifier) which represents the entire [`AM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator.aspx)/[`PM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator.aspx) designator of your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx).

```
DateTime.Parse("11/13/2014 12:00 PM").ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm tt")
```

Your program thinks your `a` and `p` characters as a literal string delimiter and [`m` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mSpecifier) is for minutes. Since your single digit minute of your `DateTime` is `0`, your `am / pm` will be `a0 / p0`

And remember, [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator*. That means if your `CurrentCulture`'s [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `/`, your result will have your current date separator, not `/`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do this programmatically.  For the particular case of "M/d/yyyy h:mm am/pm", I would just change the format string to use "tt" instead of "am/pm".  My code needs to work for any format the user sets on the control.

Comment: @JoeyAdams As I said, there is no `am` or `pm` as a custom specifiers. You can still use them as literal string delimiter like `'am'` and `'pm'` but that's not good for your case. `tt` specifier will change your hour parts as after noon or before noon. For example, if your hour `17:00`, `h:mm tt` represents `5:00 PM`, if it `11:00`, `h:mm tt` represents `11:00 AM`.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to set a Word date content control's value to a date, respecting its formatting:

```
DateTime dt = ...;
ContentControl contentControl = ...;

contentControl.Range.Text = ""; // ensure Word reformats date
contentControl.Range.Text = dt.ToString();
```

Setting the content control text property is like typing a value into the content control as a user.  When you type a date into the content control, Word parses and reformats it, or shows the text as given if it couldn't parse it.

The `.Text = ""` prevents Word from using the formatting given by .ToString() when the date being assigned is the same as the date already in the control.  I found that when a date picker content control is mapped to a custom XML value, if I change the date, Word will reformat it, but if I change the formatting of the date (e.g. change "February" to "Feb" or even change "Tuesday" to "Saturday"), Word will preserve my formatting.  By clearing the content control text first, Word treats the date assignment as a value change and thus reformats the date.